# Is there a way to reference the instance in decorators inside a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using [pyglet](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home) and pyglet uses decorators in order to deal with events. I'm subclassing `pyglet.window.Window` in my own class:

```
class YApp(YData, pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self, screen_width=1024, screen_height=768, fullscreen=False, locked_mouse=False):
        YData.__init__(self, "config.yur")
        if not self.data:
            self.data = {
                    "SCREEN_WIDTH": screen_width,
                    "SCREEN_HEIGHT": screen_height,
                    "FULLSCREEN": fullscreen,
                    "LOCKED_MOUSE": locked_mouse}
        self.write(self.data_name)
        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, self.data["SCREEN_WIDTH"], self.data["SCREEN_HEIGHT"], fullscreen=self.data["FULLSCREEN"])
        if self.data["LOCKED_MOUSE"]:
            self.set_exclusive_mouse()

    def run(self):
        pyglet.app.run()

    @self.event # HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    def on_key_press(key, modifiers):
        if key == pyglet.window.key.UP or key == pyglet.window.key.W:
            pass
        elif key == pyglet.window.key.DOWN or key == pyglet.window.key.S:
            pass
        elif key == pyglet.window.key.LEFT or key == pyglet.window.key.A:
            pass
        elif key == pyglet.window.key.RIGHT or key == pyglet.window.key.D:
            pass
```

This decorator, usually, would be applied outside of the class in some function, using the "outside" instance of pyglet.window.Window (`@app.event`, for example). But, how could I reference the instance in the decorator inside the class without getting a NameError? If I run the above code, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "core.py", line 188, in <module>
    class YApp(YData, pyglet.window.Window):
  File "core.py", line 206, in YApp
    @self.event
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `self` (or the class name, `YApp`) isn't in scope during the class definition. If `event` is a class or static method, you could reference it directly on the class (`@...Window.event`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's unfortunately not possible.  The decorator is executed when defining the class, but you can't (normally) create an instance of a class before it's defined.

But you don't have to do this.  As shown in the [pyglet documentation](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/windowing.html#subclassing-window) you can add event handlers by simply defining them as a method.  Don't forget the `self` parameter!

Example:

```
class YApp(YData, pyglet.window.Window):
    # I omitted __init__() and run() from your example

    # no need for a decorator
    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        pass  # your event handler
```